# How to get older versions of Google Spreadsheet data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to compare different versions of Spreadsheet data and highlight differences between the two versions. I know there is Version History feature, but what I'm trying is to get all the revision history when choosing the version.(i.e. if the latest version is five and I choose two, I want to get all the revisions made between version two and five).

I know how to access to the current version, but I'm stuck with how to do this with older versions. Is there any way to access to older versions as the same manner as the following code?

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
var sheetdata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the values from other version of Spreadsheet using the following script.

  ```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetdata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  ```
- You have already got the revision ID of the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? When only values are retrieved from the other version of Spreadsheet, how about this workaround? Unfortunately, the Spreadsheet of the some revision cannot be directly retrieved as the Spreadsheet. So in this workaround, it is converted to other format and retrieved the values. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Retrieve Spreadsheet of other version as the excel format.
2. Convert the excel format to Google Spreadsheet.

   - By this, the values are separated to each sheet.
3. Retrieve values using your script.

#### Sample script:

Before you run this script, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And set the variables of `spreadsheetId` and `revisionId`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  var revisionId = "###"; // Please set the revision ID.

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=" + spreadsheetId + "&revision=" + revisionId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}}).getBlob();
  var id = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS, title: revisionId}, blob).id;


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetdata = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, a Spreadsheet of the version is created to the root folder.

  - The filename is the revision ID.
- When you want to retrieve the revision IDs of the Spreadsheet, please use Revisions: list.

#### References:

- [Download and publish file revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions)
- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [Revisions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Would it work any better to use the downloadUrl provided from [Drive.Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/get) (e.g., what type of file does that url return; any different from `UrlFetchApp` above)?

Comment: @Tanaike This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks so much!

Comment: @sinaraheneba Thank you for your suggestion. I proposed above method from the following reason. The endpoint for exporting file retrieved by Drive.Revisions.get is the same with that of above method. Also the file ID and revision ID are required for both. From this situation, I proposed above method which is lower process cost. If I misunderstood your suggestion, please tell me.

Comment: @m3-bit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.