# Is cell edit history accessible programmatically in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In have an installed trigger for onEdit and an installed trigger for onChange. I log the contents of the event object that is passed in as below

```
function installedOnChange(e) {
    var me = CalleeName(arguments);
    Logger.log("%s: %s", me, JSON.stringify(e));
```

(CalleeName is defined as

```
function CalleeName(a) {
    return a.callee.toString().split(" ")[1].split("(")[0].trim();
}
```

).

The stringification of the event contains `.oldvalue` and `.value` **except** in the situation where a cell is ^C copied and then ^V pasted into another cell. In *that* case, neither are given. For example, here we have the onEdit and onChange event data for copying into J19:

```
onEdit: {"authMode":"FULL","range":{"columnEnd":10,"columnStart":10,"rowEnd":19,"rowStart":19},"source":{},"triggerUid":"3504192","user":{"email":"data@blahblahblah","nickname":"data"}}

onChange: {"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"EDIT","source":{},"triggerUid":"3538611","user":{"email":"data@blahblahblah","nickname":"data"}}
```

As you can see, no `.value` and no `.oldvalue`.

I can equivalence the `.value` by evaluating `e.source.getActiveCell().getValue()` however, I cannot -- thus far -- establish what the *previous* value of the cell was, that is, what the destination cell held before the ^V paste was issued.

It occurred to me that perhaps this value might be available in the Show Edit History, a list available by right-clicking a cell in the sheet. However, I cannot find a programmatic interface to that information. Does such a thing exist? If so, how? and if not, where do I post a change request?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no built-in methods for directly retrieving the history of each cell in Spreadsheet service of Google Apps Script. So as several workarounds, how about using the revision data? [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57387113/7108653) Or how about using a temporal Spreadsheet saving the old values? [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/73edaed1268a6d07118aed538aa5608d) But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: These are interesting ideas. However, I fear that speed of processing may not be on my side were I to implement them. But thank you for your interest.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my proposals were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike and what about other scripting systems? (Python, PHP, ... do have gsheet api interfaces). Do you know if google sheet CELL history is available from any of them? Thanks