# Google Sheet Script: Can I access the cell edit history that has been already occurred via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I already have a google sheet that is shared with around 150 people. And the sheet has some data entered by different people. Each row is dedicated to a specific person. The row also contains the email address of the specific person. I would like to know that is the data entered into a specific row done by the person that was dedicated for the row.

I know I can do that by "*show edit history*", but it has many data, and it's better to do it by script. I google about it and have got some solutions that involves the *onEdit()* method. What I understand onEdit() method is for future data entry. But in my case, I already have the data entered by different persons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this is that same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61004713/is-cell-edit-history-accessible-programmatically-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score -1):

onEdit() method allows you to trigger a function when an edit has been made in the sheet so this is not what you are looking for.

You can try using Drive API to access and list the revision history of a file.

Reference:

[Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/list)