# Google Sheets Script to Restore a named version

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to see if anyone know of a script that could restore a named version of a google sheet.

The sheets we have set up allows data input and filter and when they send the data through another script we would like to have the final process restore a named version (Currently it just clears the sheet). The reason for this is that on the odd occasion someone will delete cells or overwrite formula's breaking it for next use, requiring us to go and restore the version. Just seeing if there is a way to automatically restore the version after they are complete?

Comment: Have you tried add a gentle cell protection to those areas you don't want them to break. (gentle meaning it gives a popup warning rather than is locked to certain users)

Comment: You could restore with a template.

Comment: You can use [Drive.Revisions.update(resource, fileId, revisionId)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get older versions of Google Spreadsheet data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387113/how-to-get-older-versions-of-google-spreadsheet-data)

Comment: I don't think you cannot directly "restore" your spreadsheet to a previous revision. What you can do is (1) retrieve this revision, (2) get its content, and (3) set this content to your spreadsheet. Also, it's currently not possible to retrieve a revision by its **name** (there is an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115421149) regarding this). You would need to retrieve the revision via `revisionId` instead. Do you think this could be a valid approach? Is it always the same revision you want to restore. If that's the case, I'd post an answer with this.