# History of changes of specific cell in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, revision-history

There is a google spreadsheet document, changed by multiple people.
I want to check full history of changes of specific cell.

There is an option "show edit history" - but it's not useful, because in situation of restoring version from history it starts with moment of restoring and information "This edit was a result of a restored past version".

An alternative i've found is check every version in history and manually look at changes in cell (or use bisection during looking into history to found moment of change).

I would like to be able seeing full history of changes in specific cell - for example D18. How to achieve that?

I consider automatic exporting document to csv and store history in git -but it need another separate process and some kind of infrastructure. Maybe there is better way to track changes?

Answer (score 0):

To record changes to one or more cells from now on, use my [logChanges_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/80616417?msgid=80684709) script.

If you are a programmer, you get past revisions through the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api) using the [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) resource, but that requires a bit of coding. See [How to get older versions of Google Spreadsheet data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387413/13045193) for sample code.